# Fetch value from ConfigMap (K8s) to Angular application

Tags: angular, kubernetes, configmap

I am using Openshift for CI purpose. I have angular application for which I need to fetch the values from configMap to my angular application. I know the steps for ConfigMap creation and I created the ConfigMap with data in it. But I am not getting how to fetch those values.
Any help would be appreciated!